# Abbreviation of words only in 3 letters!

Tags: abbreviations

Is there a Document or Dictionary to shows words in short form? (in 3 letters)

for example Abbreviation of Ireland is: IRL

I have to write some words (like computer/internet/technology/...) just in three letters..

Is there a rule to do this?

Comment: Requests for good references are off topic here (but you could ask on [meta] instead). Requests for words/abbreviations require more information about the context where they'll be used.

Comment: IRL comes from an ISO standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3. These are to some degree arbitrary - Australia is AUS and Austria AUT - so no absolute rule is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link might help you:  http://www.acronymfinder.com/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [acronymfinder.com](http://www.acronymfinder.com/), you can use [worldatlas.com](http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm) for finding the 2 or 3 letter abbreviations for country codes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, [www.xe.com/iso4217.php](http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php) will show you the ISO 4217 three-letter abbreviations for world currencies, such as [INR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee) for Indian Rupee and [IDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_rupiah) for Indonesian Rupiah.